# How to make Notification drop down and not only show on Status Bar?

Tags: notifications, android-notifications

I'm doing a notification on android and want it to drop-down instead of only showing on the status bar, but I can't seem to make it work. I've tried changing priority, importance of the channel, etc, but it won't work. Can someone help?

The code is this:

```
public class MainActivity4 extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);
    createNotificationChannel();
}

public void showTopDownNotif(View v) {
    int icon = R.drawable.alarm_icon;
    String title = "Próxima alarman en: ";
    String text = "15 min";

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "nchannel");
    builder.setSmallIcon(icon);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(text);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);
    builder.setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

    NotificationManagerCompat notifManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notifManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = "NotifChannel";
        String description = "Canal de notificaciones";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("nchannel", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

}